Is it possible to detect tap on root item of CollectionView using an NSDiffableDataSourceSectionSnapshot
The following code displays some data in a collectionView in a hierarchical display
class PrimaryCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
enum Section: CaseIterable {
    case Main
}

struct Item: Hashable {
var mainText: String
var type: String
}
var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item>! = nil
var listConfiguration = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .sidebar)
let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.list(using: listConfiguration)
self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
   let containerCellRegistration =    UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, Item> { (cell, indexPath, item) in
       var contentConfiguration = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
       contentConfiguration.text = item.mainText
       cell.contentConfiguration = contentConfiguration
       let disclosureOptions = UICellAccessory.OutlineDisclosureOptions(style: .header)
       cell.accessories = [.outlineDisclosure(options:disclosureOptions)]
   }

    let cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, Item> { cell, indexPath, item in
        var contentConfiguration = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
        contentConfiguration.text = item.mainText
        cell.contentConfiguration = contentConfiguration
    }

    dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item>(collectionView: self.collectionView) {
        (collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: IndexPath, item: Item) -> UICollectionViewCell? in

        if item.type == "child" {
            return collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: cellRegistration, for: indexPath, item: item)
        } else {
            return collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: containerCellRegistration, for: indexPath, item: item)
        }
    }

    var snapShot = NSDiffableDataSourceSectionSnapshot<Item>()
    let rootItem = Item(mainText: "Root item", type: "parent")
    snapShot.append([rootItem]
    let childItem = Item(mainText: "Child item", type: "child")
    snapShot.append([childItem], to: rootItem)
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView
                             : UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath
                             : IndexPath) {
guard let selectedItem = self.dataSource.itemIdentifier(for: indexPath) else {
    return
}
print("Item = \(String(describing: self.dataSource.itemIdentifier(for: IndexPath(indexes: indexPath))))")
}

}
When the root item is selected the list is expanded to show the child item. And when the child item is selected "didSelectItemAt" is called.
My question is, is it possible to detect when the root item is selected?
Thanks in advance.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
